# How I can get sub-image (crop) based on another image transparent area

Tags: python, php, image-processing, opencv

I have 2 sets of images.
Set A are photos and set B are frames with transparent background.

I need to prepare the photo in order to be printed on a UV machine and to obtain a paint.

Basically this is the photo:
[image]

The frame is looking like the follow:
[image]

The inside area is transparent. All the frames are in PNG format and all of them have in middle a unregulated transparent area.

Basically what the user is doing now is placing the frame on top of the photo and is adjusting zoom and pan until he obtains a good preview of the painting:

[image]

After this I am saving in a database the width + height of both images (photo and frame) and the  position (x,y) relative to a origin point that is fixed.

Using this parameters I am able to reposition everthing the same on server side where I need now to do the last step: I need to extract photo that is visible in the transparent area of the frame.

Basically what I need to obtain is this:

[image]

On Photoshop I was able to select the frame layer, to automatically select the area that is transparent and then to use this selection to crop the photo from other layer.

But I need to do this automatically using for example OpenCV with Python or PHP with some kind of library.

Any idea about how I can accomplish this?

Comment: The frame image is transparent so it has an alpha channel. Remove the alpha channel, invert it and put that into the alpha channel of the image that has the cat inside the frame

Comment: also https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780

Comment: Create a mask from inRange function and the transparency channel of the image. Then use the mask and subimages and maybe .setTo function or .copyTo function to manipulate  images according to that mask.